# Set max-height on inner div so scroll bars appear, but not on parent div

Tags: html, css

I have my HTML, CSS set up as per the code below. I have also added a JSFiddle link since it will be far more convenient to see the code in action.

The problem I'm having is that when there is a lot of text in the `#inner-right` div within the `#right-col` div, I want a scrollbar to appear for `#inner-right` **only**. My current code shows two scrollbars: `#inner-div` and `#right-col`. If I change the CSS on `#right-col` to `overflow: hidden` so as to get rid of the outer scroll-bar, the inner scroll bar disappears as well, and `#inner-right` no longer respects the `max-height` rule.

How can I set it up such that the scroll bar only shows up on `#inner-right` when it's contents grow too large.

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/C8MuZ/10/)

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;    
}
#wrapper {
    height: 100%;
    display: table;
    width: 700px;
}
#header, #footer {
    display: table-row;
    height: 30px;
}
#body {
    height: 100%;
    display: table-row;
    background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
#left-col, #right-col {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 320px;
    height: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    margin-right: 20px;
    border: 2px black solid;
    vertical-align: top;
    padding: 3px;
    overflow: auto;    
}
#inner-right {
    height: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    background: ivory;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="header">Header</div>
    <div id="body">
        <div id="left-col">
            Lorem ipsum ... little text
        </div>
        <div id="right-col">
            <div id="header-text">Header</div>
            <div id="inner-right">
            Lorem ipsum ...lots of text
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer">Footer</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 87, accepted):

If you make

`overflow: hidden` in the outer div and `overflow-y: scroll` in the inner div it will work.

http://jsfiddle.net/C8MuZ/11/

Comment: You've hard-coded the heights to 300px. I'm unable to do that. I need to leave heights at 100%;

Comment: I thought jsfiddle auto-scrolls the output container so I hard coded it. Doesn't it work in your web site?

Comment: So did it really work without hard-coding the height?

Comment: I've got the same problem - the question is to make it work without hard-coding the height

Answer (score 10):

**This would work just fine, set the height to desired pixel**

```
#inner-right{
            height: 100px;
            overflow:auto;
            }
```

Answer (score 3):

set this :

```
#inner-right {
    height: 100%;
    max-height: 96%;//change here
    overflow: auto;
    background: ivory;
}
```

this will solve your problem.

Comment: I need the inner div to be 100% height too. I guess if I can't figure anything else out, I'll settle for this.

Comment: @xbonez How is it possible to do the inner div height 100% because you have add the one more div here with title Header. then you can use only remaining part. that's why you need to decrease some height of inner div.

Comment: you use these words '100% height' but i don't think it means what you think it means.

Answer (score 1):

It might be easier to use JavaScript or jquery for this. Assuming that the height of the header and the footer is 200 then the code will be:

```
function SetHeight(){
    var h = $(window).height();
    $("#inner-right").height(h-200);    
}

$(document).ready(SetHeight);
$(window).resize(SetHeight);
```

Comment: Please no more javascript xd