# How do I set the height of a column in CSS grid in order to make it scrollable?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I removed excess code but I think this is the core of what I need done. I am currently mapping a list of activities into the first grid__column. However, that list is very long of 40 items and I need to scroll the whole page to see it. I want to be able to set a height on this 1st column then set `overflow: scroll` on it to limit the view to maybe 10 items and scroll for the rest. I can't seem to be able to set a height on the column or put overflow on it.

```
#main-content.container {
    padding: 0 20px;
    max-width: 1200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 3fr;
    gap: 74px;
}

.grid__column {
    height: 10rem;
}
```

html:

```
<div id="main-content" className="container">
    <div className="grid">
        <div className="grid__column">
            <div className="first-grid__column-title">Scroll Table</div>
            <ActivitiesGuide />
        </div>

        <div className="grid__column">
            <div className="second-grid__column-title">Second Column</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

John, I'm not sure exactly what you are asking, but I did find this question that might be able to help you.

[adding scrolling to divs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15632287/set-max-height-on-inner-div-so-scroll-bars-appear-but-not-on-parent-div)

I hope this give you insight, or an idea in the right direction.